# Web API - How to accept comma separated list of parameter values via query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API project I am working on in Visual Studio 2013, and I'd like for my Controllers to accept a comma separated list of values via the query string, similar to this:

```
http://localhost:12345/api/Procedures/1?embed=doctors,drugs&fields=fieldA,fieldB,fieldC
```

The reason for this is that I'd like to be able to control if related resources (additional tables) are queried via custom embedding using the **embed** parameter, and control what fields are returned from the base object using the **fields** parameter.

I've done some searching on Google but most of what is being suggested relates to extending IModelBinder (http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/)  or setting up a custom ActionFilterAttribute ([Convert custom action filter for Web API use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941669/convert-custom-action-filter-for-web-api-use)) which seems like overkill for something relatively simple.

FYI I am using an Entity Framework dbContext class to connect to my database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comma character does not have any specific meaning in HTTP query strings so it does not get treated as a separator by out-of-the-box model binding mechanisms.

As far as I know the approach you mentioned with custom attributes is the simplest you can get. And it does not look like an overkill considering you will only implement the attribute once and use everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I went ahead and implemented the custom attribute option.